# Python3 subprocess can't run command "la" or "ll"

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

```
completeProcess = subprocess.run("la")
```

This is my code to run commands via python, and it raise this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_senior.py", line 171, in <module>
    completeProcess = subprocess.run("la") # doesn't capture output
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'la'
```

My OS is ubuntu, and when enter "la" in terminal, it will list files(include hidden files) in current working directory. and "ll" cmd will list file details. but I can't use them in python's subprocess api

How can I achieve this function? Is there any common api to run commands or just the python didn't recognize "la"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la is an alias for 'ls -A'. That comes as a default shell alias in systems like Ubuntu. If you wanna run it just use:

```
completeProcess = subprocess.run(["ls","-A"])
```

and if you are looking for the stdout you can use something like:

```
completeProcess = subprocess.run(["ls","-A"] , stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(completeProcess.stdout.decode())
```

Comment: Works! Thanks too much! Besides, where can I find any docs about the default shell alias? I found them on .bashrc, are these alias only for ubuntu?

Comment: Type $alias to get a list of all active ones. The settings are done in a file called  '.bashrc' in your home directory.